# Using grep to filter calls to service in logs

Tags: unix, filter, grep

I'm trying to filter the number of times a service is called by a different user in a log file.

I was thinking about using uniq -c, but almost all lines are unique thanks to the timestamp. What I want is to ignore the parts of the line I don't need and just focus on the service name and the call id which identifies each separate call.

The log format is something like this:

```
27/02/2017 00:00:00 [useremail@email.com] [sessioninfo(**callId**)] **serviceName**
```

Being callId and serviceName the strings I want to filter.

And my required output would be the count of each different callId that is found in the same line as the service call.

For example for the input :

```
27/02/2017 00:00:00 [useremail@email.com] [sessioninfo(12345)] service1
27/02/2017 00:00:01 [useremail1@email.com] [sessioninfo(12346)] service1
27/02/2017 00:00:02 [useremail2@email.com] [sessioninfo(12347)] service1
27/02/2017 00:00:00 [useremail@email.com] [sessioninfo(12345)] service1
```

The output would be 3, because one of the lines is using the same callId.

Is there any way I could achieve this with a grep, or would I need to create more advanced script to do the job?

Comment: please edit your Q to show your required output from your input. AND pease read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following awk:

```
awk -F '[\\(\\)\\]]+' '{ print $3 " " $4 }' somelog.log
```

You may combine it later with sort and then uniq and get the count:

```
awk -F '[\\(\\)\\]]+' '{ print $3 " " $4 }' somelog.log | sort | uniq
```

Answer (score 1):

> What I want is to ignore the parts of the line I don't need.

In your case, what you need is the **`-f`** option of `uniq`:

```
 -f num  Ignore the first num  fields in each input line when doing comparisons.  A
         field is a  string of non-blank characters separated  from adjacent fields 
         by blanks. Field numbers are one based, i.e., the first field is field one.
```

So you would `sort` the log file, find unique lines (discounting the first three fields) with `uniq -f3` and then find the number of such lines with `wc -l`.

i.e.

```
sort out.log | uniq -f 3 | wc -l
```